# mongocxx: Inserting a Datetime

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++-chrono, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm trying to insert a date and time into mongocxx after parsing a data file, my actual datetime is:

```
2007/12/01 00:00:00
```

That is, December 1, 2007 at midnight. I have this code:

```
static bsoncxx::document::value make_doc(sm_struct const sm) {
    std::tm t{0};
    t.tm_sec = 0;
    t.tm_min=(int)sm.minute;
    t.tm_hour=(int)sm.hour;
    t.tm_mday=(int)sm.day-1;
    t.tm_mon=(int)sm.month;
    t.tm_year=sm.year-1900;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    std::time_t tt = mktime(&t);

    std::cout << sm.year << " " << t.tm_year << "/" << t.tm_mon << "/" << t.tm_mday << " " << t.tm_hour << ":" << t.tm_min << std::endl;
    bsoncxx::document::value document = bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document(
        bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp("datetime", bsoncxx::types::b_date{
            std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(tt)
        }),
    );
    return document;
}
```

Running my code I get this on stdout:

```
2007 107/11/31 0:0
```

When I check my date in the database I get:

```
ISODate("2007-12-30T13:30:00.000+0000")
```

How come the hours and minutes are not being set correctly here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks correct you insert Dec 31, 2007 at midnight local time in Adelaide which is Dec 30, 2007 13:30 (UTC). You can convert the UTC time back to your local time when you show it.

```
Adelaide, Australia    Mon, 31 Dec 2007 at 00:00 ACDT    
UTC, Time Zone         Sun, 30 Dec 2007 at 13:30
```

Source: [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20071230T133000&p1=5&p2=1440)

Comment: Thanks, I used `gmtime` instead of `mktime` and it worked.

Comment: Excellent, Please mark my answer as correct. Cheers